# Jquery select option value reset to previous

Tags: javascript

Check out this jfiddle:
Select an option and then select another option, you'll see the alert for reset to previous.
If you select the "Select an option" it does what I want but I can't figure how to do it for each selected option.

Any guidance would be really appreciated!

Comment: who edited this question removed all code and links  ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be as simple as changing this:

```
var price_name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
```

to

```
var price_name = jQuery(this).val();
```

(probably unnecessary, but here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k36Qt/1/)

Comment: When you select the "select an option.." option, it removes the last option value that was selected.

Comment: I'm sure it is just a little code like that, but i'm banging my head against the table trying to figure out what I can do, without rewriting the thing.

Comment: Comment the intended behavior at  the branches in your sample code.

Comment: Sorry, i used alert instead with what the behavior of the option is supposed to be doing..or atleast what i'm trying to get it to do..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var prevValue = 0;
jQuery("select").change(function () {
    var text_selectbox = jQuery(this).find(":selected").text();
    var price_process = 0;
    var r = /[0-9.]+/g;
    var s = text_selectbox;
    var m;
    while ( ( m = r.exec( s ) ) != null ) {
      price_process = m[0] ;
    }
    var price = parseFloat( price_process );
    price = $.isNumeric(price) ? price : 0;

    var product_price = parseFloat( jQuery("p.price span.amount").html().replace( '$','' ) ); 
    var total_price = product_price;

    total_price = total_price - prevValue + price;
    prevValue = price;

    jQuery("p.price span.amount").html( "$" + total_price );

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xE8YJ/)

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I get an $NaN if i select "select an option..", what could I do to have it revert back to the original?